# How to marginalize away a nuisance parameter in a multivariate Gaussian?

Tags: distributions, likelihood, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have a likelihood function with a nuisance parameter $t_0$. The likelihood is as follows:
$$\log L (\vec{t}, t_0) = -\frac{1}{2} (\vec{t} - t_0)^T \Sigma^{-1}(\vec{t} - t_0),$$
where $\vec{t}$ are the actual time residuals that are distributed like this. Since the absolute start is not known, there is this offset $t_0$. The covariance matrix is known, and is diagonal: $\Sigma_{ii} = \sigma_i^2$.

I would like to integrate out this nuisance parameter $t_0$. Physically, it makes sense to just take $\vec{t}$ relative to its first value $t[0]$ and incorporate this into a now non-diagonal covariance matrix. This would result in the $\log{L}$ being only dependent on $\vec{t}_d = \vec{t}[1,...,N]-t[0]$ (in Python: `td=t[1:]-t[0]`)
$$\log{L}(\vec{t}_d) = -\frac{1}{2} (\vec{t}_\text{d})^T \Sigma_d^{-1}\vec{t}_d,$$
where $\Sigma_d = \mathrm{diag}(\sigma_i^2) + \sigma_0^2$ the covariance matrix of $\vec{t}_d$, which is nondiagonal due to the correlation between errors because all subtract the same normal-distributed value of $\vec{t}[0]$.

**Question:**
How to show that
$$\int\mathrm{d}t_0 L (\vec{t}, t_0) = L(\vec{t}_d).$$

I verified with Mathematica that this is indeed true in the $N=2,3$ cases, but failed to work out something general. I would also be happy with references that show something this, or some generalization of it.

Comment: Is $\Sigma$ known or are all the entries on the diagonal unknown free parameters?  When you integrate out the mean you end up with a restricted likelihood (REML) for which there are well known formulas, see e.g. [Harville 1974](https://www.math.ntnu.no/emner/TMA4315/2020h/Harville-1974.pdf) or [Fahrmeir et. al. 2013](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642343322) p. 373.

Comment: Yes, $\Sigma$ is known. Thank you for the references, I will take a look at them!